# check if a node has a property

Tags: asp.net-4.0, umbraco

I'm trying to check if a certain node has a property "footerTextTitle" by:

```
@foreach (var nodeLink in footerTop.ChildrenAsList.Where(n => n.GetProperty("footerTextTitle").IsNull() == true))
  {
    <li><a href='@nodeLink.GetProperty("footerLinkUrl").Value.ToString()'>@nodeLink.GetProperty("footerLinkTitle").Value.ToString()</a></li>
  }
```

and getting a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.

How can I do this ?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm actually getting this error inside a macro this razor script is attached to, so I can't really see the stack trace. Unless there's another way to see it ??? (pardon the ignorance)

Comment: turns out the solution is simple :

    if (n.GetProperty("footerTextTitle") == null) ...

Comment: You can put that in the `Where` call too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To check if a property exists simply check if the property is null like below**

```
@foreach (var nodeLink in footerTop.ChildrenAsList.Where(n => n.GetProperty("footerTextTitle") == null))
  {
    <li><a href='@nodeLink.GetProperty("footerLinkUrl").Value.ToString()'>@nodeLink.GetProperty("footerLinkTitle").Value.ToString()</a></li>
  }
```

**P.S. To debug, append this to the url**

http://www.example.com/page.aspx`?umbDebugShowTrace=true`